# Does Google AdWords Charges Multiple Times per click per Ads Impression?

Tags: google-ads-api

[This](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2016/10/google-click-id-gclid-will-now-be.html) article says that google will now generate only 1 gclid per ad impression. This means that when a user clicks multiple times on an ad within a single impression, only one gclid is generated. How does this affects the ad cost? Will they still charge us:

1. per click (every user click)?
2. per ads (regardless of how many times a user clicks on the same ads)?
3. per click per ads per impression?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. Consider asking Google Ads support this question instead; only they can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Our marketing guy got a response from Google rep re: "Do you charge per click on the same ad within the same impression? Or just for the 1st click?"

Answer: Technically it is for any click. However, repeat clicks from the same impression and same IP will likely get flagged as invalid and uncharged.

Answer (score 0):

Per Google's policy:

> You can be charged a maximum of 2 clicks per ad impression. Not per user.

So yes, technically you can be charged twice and even more if your ad is displayed on another page to the same user.